# How to get specific data, but not a complete answer in mongodb/nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection of the following kind

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbb299f06229dddbaab553b"),
    "phone" : "+38 (031) 231-23-21",
    "date_call" : "2018-10-08",
    "adress_delivery" : "1",
    "quantity_concrete" : "1",
    "state" : "200",
    "comments" : "1",
    "is_order" : "n",
    "date_delivery" : "",
    "quantity_orders" : "",
    "summ_order" : "",
    "profit" : "",
    "id" : "0"
}
```

When requested in the terminal

```
db.getCollection("customers").find(
    {
        "$and" : [
            {
                "date_call" : {
                    "$lte" : "2018-10-10"
                }
            },
            {
                "date_call" : {
                    "$gte" : "2018-09-24"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "phone" : 1,
        "is_order" : 1
    }
);
```

I get the answer

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5bbb299f06229dddbaab553b"),
  "phone" : "+38 (031) 231-23-21",
  "is_order" : "n"
}
```

When requested same query in the nodeJS

```
client.db(“mongoDB”).collection("customers").find(
    {
        "$and": [
            {
                "date_call": {
                    "$lte" : "2018-10-14"
                }
            },
            {
                "date_call": {
                    "$gte" : "2018-09-24"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        “phone”: 1,
        "is_order": 1
    }
)
```

I get a complete answer, not “phone” and “is_order” as set in the query. Please tell me how can I get only the specified data?

Comment: pass {fields:{"phone": 1, "is_order":1}} as projection object

Answer (score 0):

You can use `project` function in this way

```
client.db("mongoDB").collection("customers").find(
    {
        "$and": [
            {
                "date_call": {
                    "$lte" : "2018-10-14"
                }
            },
            {
                "date_call": {
                    "$gte" : "2018-09-24"
                }
            }
        ]
    })
    .project(
    {
        "phone": 1,
        "is_order": 1
    })
    .toArray((err, res) => {
        //your code here
    })
```

Also base on @Astro comment pass `{fields:{"phone": 1, "is_order":1}}` as projection object